# T-SQL query to find common features

Tags: t-sql

I have this table:

```
ID    Value
------------
1     car
1     moto
2     car
2     moto
3     moto
3     apple
4     gel
4     moto
5     NULL
```

note that `moto` is common to all IDs.

I would to obtain a single row with this result

```
car*, moto, apple*, gel*
```

i.e.

- `car, apple, gel` with an asterisk because is present but NOT in all IDs
- `moto` without an asterisk because is COMMON to all IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ID + Value` are Unique

```
SELECT Value, CASE WHEN COUNT(*) <> (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM MyTable) THEN '*' ELSE '' END AS Asterisk FROM MyTable WHERE Value IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Value
```

Note that this won't group in a single line. And note that your question is wrong. `ID` `5` is an ID, so `moto` isn't common to all the `ID`s. It's common to all the `ID`s that have at least a value.

If we filter these `ID`s as written,

```
SELECT Value, CASE WHEN COUNT(*) <> (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM MyTable WHERE Value IS NOT NULL) THEN '*' ELSE '' END FROM MyTable WHERE Value IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Value
```

To "merge" the `*` with `Value`, simply replace the `,` with a `+`, like:

```
SELECT Value + CASE WHEN COUNT(*) <> (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM MyTable WHERE Value IS NOT NULL) THEN '*' ELSE '' END Value FROM MyTable WHERE Value IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Value
```

To make a single line use one of https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/ I'll add that, sadly, tsql doesn't have any native method to do it, and all the alternatives are a little ugly :-)

In general, the string aggregation part is quite common on SO (and outside of it) [Concatenate row values T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874966/concatenate-row-values-t-sql), [tsql aggregate string for group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787498/tsql-aggregate-string-for-group-by), [Implode type function in SQL Server 2000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534724/implode-type-function-in-sql-server-2000), [How to return multiple values in one column (T-SQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122942/how-to-return-multiple-values-in-one-column-t-sql) and too many others to count :-)

Comment: Why Oracle? The OP specifies TSQL.

Comment: @MartinSmith Because I gave him the wrong link :-) I collected some links about STRING_AGG substitutes and I gave him the wrong one